# When using Click2Run/SxS MS Access DBMS via ADO, how can I access Database object?

Tags: ms-access, dao, ms-access-2016, side-by-side

It's been our experience that non C2R MS Access DBMS installations seem to break after any MS Office SxS install or update occurs.  Have seen this with 2007, 2010, and 2016.  We didn't try 2013.  To get the application working again, we need to repair the MS Access installation that we are using.

Presently, we're only using the 32 bit provider.  We have been using the DAO Database object to perform database restructuring.

Thinking of migrating to the Click2Run MS Access 2019, I tried to use this instead but found that DBEngine is not made available outside the C2R "bubble".  I don't see a way I can instantiate or ask for an existing Database instance.  This is a problem because then the database restructuring won't work.

When using Click2Run/SxS MS Access DBMS via ADO, how can I access Database object to be able to use DAO to restructure the database?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to install the ACE engine from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

However, if you want to know how this really works?

Well, it rather important to distinguish between Access. Access is a developers tool like vb.net, or FoxPro or whatever. It allows you to write code, and consume data from a database of your choosing.

So Access is not the database nor is access a database. I mean, how does one create forms and a user interface with SQL server? You can't!!!

So a few things:

Up to Access 2010:
If you install Access system, then it ALSO installs a version of the database engine (used to be called JET, but now it called ACE).

So, installing access the development system, or even the access runtime?
It would install and register and expose a copy of the ACE database engine.

You could thus use the ACE database engine in 3rd party tools. (such as VB6, or say vb.net/ c# .net).

Now, for Access 2013, and 2016? Well by default since most office installs are C2R, they also changed that when installing 2013 and 2016 they DO NOT expose a external copy of the ACE data engine.

For 2019, due to some confusing by the general developer community? Well  they now re-introduced that installing Access (full edition, or runtime) is NOW back to the way it was in the past.

That past was installing Access also installed a EXPOSED copy of ACE.

So, for 2019, this long time setup has returned (even for C2R).

Just as the whole community was getting used to this new setup, we now back to what it was like in the past!!

Having a self contained and NON exposed copy of ACE has some rather nice advantages. One big advantage is that you can now install a different version of ACE - including the mixing of x32 and x64 ones.

So, installing Access as a develope9rs tool should not have for all these years also exposed the ACE database engine. This is especially the case since many now use Access with SQL server, or even SharePoint. So, now Access is not the database. Even a bound form to a sql table with 1 million rows of data? Access is smart, and if you open the form with a standard built in "where" clause, Access will ONLY pull the one record. I note this issue, since once again, Access is NOT a database. It is a system to build applications with, and has things like code, reports, and that of a user interface to build applications with.

Once you choose Access, you THEN choose the database, and it does not have to be ACE

Ok, now all above is clear.

To use the ACE database engine?
Simply install it. Use this link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

As noted, for 2019, the return of ACE being installed + exposed when you install Access is retuning. However, between:

So, we have for access 2010, 4 versions:
Access x32 - full edition
Access x32 - runtime edition
Access x64 - full edition
Access x64 - runtime edition.

For Access 2013, we have 8 versions.

Access x32 - full edition - MSI
Access x32 - runtime edition - MSI
Access x64 - full edition - MSII
Access x64 - runtime edition. NSI

Access x32 - full edition - CTR
Access x32 - runtime edition - CTR
Access x64 - full edition - CTR
Access x64 - runtime edition. CTR

So, what will and will not work. And what version to install was becoming a HUGE matrix of possibilities.

Bottom line:
If you need ACE for external 3rd party use? Then install the ACE engine, and NOT bother to install access or assume Access will install a exposed copy of ACE).

I could write on for 20 more pages about the options, and what versions you can, or cannot mix. But with 8 versions that narrative will be rather large. Anyway for the time being, you can't assume that installed Access will install a exposed copy of ACE.

So, for the time being, you have to install ACE.

Over time, we will be back to how this worked in the past, and this is especially the case since MSI versions of office are becoming VERY difficult to fine, or obtain. You quite much forced to choose C2R, and MSI installs from physical media (or even a download) is a thing of the past.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  We only use ACE.  The trouble is that ACE breaks whenever an Office C2R application is installed or receives an update.  We have been using the 2010 ACE but it needs an installation repair regularly.  The 2016 ACE seems to be no better since simply installing the C2R runtime breaks it immediately.

Comment: At noted, you want to install the data engine separate. Try the link included.

Comment: We've been distributing it that way for years.  Around December, it started to get broken as often as a few times a week.  If you install the newest MS Access runtime, it breaks the older version's DBEngine directly.